# SerialPorts and multi threading - Cross Thread operation not valid

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, serial-port

This is my first time using serial ports so I just learned that they operate on a different thread, I have no clue about multi threading so I don't know where to begin fixing my code, web searches just confuses me more with things like Invoke.

Here's my whole code for a barcode scanner connected via rs232 port, i'm just receiving data and putting it on a label.

When setting the label text to the received data I get an error...

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Label1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

```
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class Form1

Dim WithEvents com4 As New SerialPort

Private Sub com4_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles com4.DataReceived
    Dim returnStr As String
    returnStr = com4.ReadExisting
    Label1.Text = returnStr
    com4.DiscardInBuffer()
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        With com4
            .PortName = "Com4"
            .BaudRate = 38400 '9600
            .Parity = Parity.None
            .DataBits = 8
            .StopBits = StopBits.One
        End With
        com4.Open()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have

```
    Label1.Text = returnStr
```

replace that line with

```
    Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                       Label1.Text = returnStr
                   End Sub)
```

edit:

Where you have

```
    Label1.Text = returnStr
```

replace that line with

```
    UpdateLabel(returnStr)
```

and add this code

```
Private Delegate Sub UpdateLabelDelegate(theText As String)
Private Sub UpdateLabel(theText As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New UpdateLabelDelegate(AddressOf UpdateLabel), theText)
    Else
        Label1.text = theText
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, i'm using visual studio 2008 and this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thanks, do you mind explaining the difference between the 2 answers? I tried the first answer on visual studio 2010 and it works. The first answer also looks a lot simpler to me.

Comment: Both of these cause the control to be manipulated on the UI thread.  The first uses a lamda which makes it simpler imho.